conditional spelling at the beginning and the end of the line
I am facing a peculiar spelling problem in Arabic language when typesetting person names with filiation. The expression "son of" should be spelled "ابن" at the beginning and at the end of the line or "بن" when it occurs between two words.
In the source code, one would usually type the short form "بن" since it is difficult to anticipate the location of the word in the rendered PDF. I am looking for a solution that would automatically substitute "بن" by "ابن" only if it is rendered at the beginning or at the end of the line.
Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!
Cheers,
MG
Note: It does not help to add unbreakable spaces as long filiations are common place in the text I am dealing with.

The only realiable way to detect where a word winds up (even within a paragraph) is after shipout using something like \tikzmark.  The information is stored in the aux file aand is accessible the next run.

I think this might be possible in LuaTeX, but don't ask me how if so, not my forte.
